# Extracting part of string according to tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I have a big string and would like to extract parts of the string. You can see an example below. I would extract the text corresponding to the `text` tags. So we have three text tags, namely `"text": "{{{VAR_2}}}"`, `"text": "Tell me. How old are you?"`, `"text": "{{{VAR_0}}}"`.

This should result in the following list of strings: `["What is your age?", "Tell me. How old are you?", "How old are you?"]`. The number of text tags varies. If no text tag is present, it should result in None.

How can this be solved in an elegant way?

```
<VAR_0>
How old are you?
</VAR_0>
<VAR_2>
What is your age?
</VAR_2>

(set:$ageask to 'true')
(set:$storybeat_01 to 1)
(set:$inputAge to -1)

<audio stopall>

<audio src="sound.wav" autoplay loop volume="100%">

<onSuccess($user_age==0,$inputAge:=age)>[[age selector]]
<onSuccess(5>age OR 100<age,$inputAge:=age)>[[impossible age]]
<onSuccess(90<age,$inputAge:=age)>[[very old]]

<interaction type="AgeNumberQuestionInteraction">
{
    "BaseClassConfig QuestionInteractionInterface": {
        "QuestionInteractionInterfaceConfig": {
            "maxQuestionRepetitionCount": 1
        },
        "QuestionSpeakingInteraction": {
            "SpeakingInteractionConfig": {
                "speech": [
                    {
                        "emotion": "HAPPY",
                        "text": "{{{VAR_2}}}"
                    },
                    {
                        "emotion": "HAPPY",
                        "text": "Tell me. How old are you?"
                    },
                    {
                        "emotion": "HAPPY",
                        "text": "{{{VAR_0}}}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
</interaction>
```

Comment: This is a mess.  What application was this designed for?  You can use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup to find the `<interaction>` tag and give you the JSON.  You can then use `json.loads` to turn that into a Python dictionary.  You can then iterate through the `"speech"` list, and if the `"text"` value has the three brackets, look up the variable using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. `import json; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser'); elm = soup.find("interaction"); json.loads(elm.text);`, should get you really close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a BeautifulSoup / JSON solution, which should be more resistant to changes in the HTML layouts.  Regular expressions are a terrible choice when working with HTML pages.

```
import bs4
import json

page = bs4.BeautifulSoup( open('x.html').read(), 'html.parser' )

data = json.loads(  page.find('interaction').text )

results = []
lst = data["BaseClassConfig QuestionInteractionInterface"]["QuestionSpeakingInteraction"]["SpeakingInteractionConfig"]["speech"]
for item in lst:
    if item['text'].startswith('{{{'):
        results.append( page.find(item['text'].strip('{}').lower()).text.strip() )
    else:
        results.append( item['text'] )
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['What is your age?', 'Tell me. How old are you?', 'How old are you?']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expressions pattern to search for the "text".

`html_doc` is your HTML above:

```py
for text in re.findall('"text": ".*?"', html_doc):
    print(text)
```

Prints:

```
"text": "{{{VAR_2}}}"
"text": "Tell me. How old are you?"
"text": "{{{VAR_0}}}"
```

Or: using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("interaction")

for text in re.findall('"text": ".*?"', tag.text):
    print(text)
```

**EDIT**: to get the `VAR` text:

```py
for text in re.findall(r"{{{(.*?)}}}", html_doc):
    print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can I then get the text of VAR_0 and VAR_2?

Comment: Use beautiful soup to get the `VAR_0` tag and `VAR_2` tag.

Comment: @Shmack This can be done without beautifulsoup. See my edit

Comment: Regular expressions are a terrible way to parse HTML.  BeautifulSoup is a much better choice.

Comment: @TimRoberts is it a "better choice" or just more elegant?

Comment: @Shmack It's better. See this (famous) post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags
My answer showed two ways, with and without regex.

Comment: Valid HTML can vary wildly.  White space is mostly irrelevant, parameters come and go, tags move around.  It's a mess to handle with regexes.

Comment: @MendelG that was the most beautiful answer ever written on Stack Overflow. Thank you both for the bit of knowledge you have imparted to me.